# php html syntax error

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert my php code embedded in html to php code with embedded html code. My IDE is throwing syntax errors. can someone please help, thanks.

html/php (working):

```
    <select name="products">
                        <option value="select">Select</option>
                        <option value="product1" <?php if (!isset($updatebtn_clicked)){ echo @$product_list['product1']; }elseif ($_POST['products'] == $product_name[0]){ echo 'selected="selected"' ;} echo
                        '>'. $product_name[0]. '</option>' ?> </select>
```

The above is a snippet for a single item in my drop down list. They just keep repeating for all products and it works.

php/html (fails to work):

```
<?php
        $select = '<select name="products">
               <option value="select">Select</option>
                value="'.$product_name[0].'"'. 
                if (!isset($updatebtn_clicked))
                { echo @$product_list[$product_name[1]]; }elseif ($_POST['products'] == $product_name[1]){ echo 'selected="selected"' ;} echo'>'. $product_name[1]. '</option></select>';
?>
```

the above generates a syntax error at the first if statement. I'm just not seeing why : /

Comment: What syntax error? Why don't you reformat it so it isn't all squished onto a single line?

Comment: well like i said the ide complains at the first if statement:
`if (!isset($updatebtn_clicked))`

Comment: Test it with PHP, not your IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second is trying to "append the `if` statement to the string". You can't write it that way.

Try this:

```
<?php
    $select = '<select name="products">
           <option value="select">Select</option>
            value="'.$product_name[0].'"';   // <- Finish assignment here

    if (!isset($updatebtn_clicked))
    { 
        $select = $select . @$product_list[$product_name[1]]; 
    }
    elseif ($_POST['products'] == $product_name[1])
    { 
        $select = $select . 'selected="selected"';
    }

    $select = $select . '>'. $product_name[1]. '</option></select>';

    echo $select;
?>
```

The difference between the first and the second thing you're trying to do is: The first thing outputs HTML with intermixed PHP. The PHP code is replaced with the output of the `echo` statements by the PHP interpreter.

The second way is that you're putting all the HTML into a variable. There, however, you can not mix PHP and HTML. You are in the scope of the PHP script all the time, so you have to write proper PHP. The statement

```
$select = 'Hello ' . if (condition) echo 'foo';
```

is not proper PHP code while

```
$select = 'Hello ';
if (condition) $select = $select . 'foo';
```

is correct PHP syntax.

**EDIT**
By the way: The second sample you posted (which I modified) does not output a valid second `option`! It should read:

```
    $select = '<select name="products">
           <option value="select">Select</option>
           <option value="'.$product_name[0].'"';   // <- Finish assignment here
```

Comment: FYI this: $select = $select . 'foo'; can be shortened too: $select .= 'foo';

Comment: I know - the entire thing could be shortened using the ternary operator. However, as the OP asked such a basic syntax question, I thought it would be best to use the full syntax (which is more intuitive) than the shortened syntax.

Comment: Thanks for that! i'm a beginner to all this so that made a lotta sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$select = "
    <select name='products'>
        <option value='select'>Select</option>
        <option value='product1' ".( (!isset($updatebtn_clicked)) ? @$product_list['product1']  : "selected='selected'").">".$product_name[0]."</option>
    </select> 
";
?>
```

Comment: I don´t urderstant the code, but the correct format in a string is this